# how to save listbox item as .config file and read it back to listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, save, load, config

In my WPF project, I have a listbox that I can add some items to it in this way:

```
//item is a class type of Product
var item = GetProductByID(ProductID);
lb_Configuration.Items.Add(item);
```

Now I want to save the listbox items when I close this application as a config file and when I reopen it, I can reload this config file to application thus to add the corresponding items to the listbox, how should I suppose to do this? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

```
    private void OpenFile_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile.Multiselect = true;
        openFile.Title = "Please Choose Your File";
        openFile.Filter = "All Files(*,*)|*.*";
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            /* What to do after open file */
            StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(openFile.FileName);
            while (sr.EndOfStream != true) ;
        }
    }

    private void SaveFile_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
        if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(saveFile.FileName);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/application-settings-overview).

Comment: in Closing event, `File.AppendAllLines`, in Loaded, `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: @LeiYang what should I do to save `ProductID` in `File.AppendAllLines()`?

Comment: @BarryLib  can you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use txt file in the application directory:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string fileName = "lst.txt";
    private List<string> lst;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closing += (s, e) =>
          {
              File.WriteAllLines(fileName, this.lst);
          };
    }
    //in other events, button click, initialize or change the lst

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.lst = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    //simulate your other changes to the lst
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lst == null)
            lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add(new Random().Next().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems not saving `lb_Configuration.items` to file `lst.txt`.

Comment: it's your own responsibility to bind lst to ui control. because that is not important part of your question.

Comment: I tried `var tmp = lb_Configuration.Items[i] as Product;
                    if (fileToSave == null)
                        fileToSave = new List<string>();
                    fileToSave.Add(tmp.ModelNumber.ToString());` but nothing saved to the **txt** file

Comment: after your `Add` call my `File.WriteAllLines(fileName, fileToSave);`

Answer (score 1):

An exact working answer can't be given since we don't know the make-up of the type `Product`, but the bottom line here is serialization - which may be extremely simple, or could get more complicated depends on the types used and exposed by the type `Product`. There are numerous tools for this: JSON.net, ServiceStack, and even built-in .net serialization.

For simplicitly and an example, consider using [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(item);
```

And to do it in the other direction...

```
var item = serializer.Deserialize<Product>(json);
```

That's a starting point, if nothing else. Obviously adjust it to serialize the whole collection, make sure all the relevant values are being serialized and deserialized and properly, and save to file:

```
File.WriteAllText(pathToFile, json);
```

To read it back:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile);
```

Comment: I think it not that complicated, I can just save `ProductID`(which is type of int variable)  in the `SaveFile_Executed` and add `var item = GetProductByID(ProductID);
lb_Configuration.Items.Add(item);` to `OpenFile_Executed`